# How to share a large git merge amongst team members

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

When merging two branches together that results in 1000+ conflicts (the branches have diverged a lot), what is the best practice for being able to divide that work up among a team of people?

Say the code base is in a Visual Studio solution comprising of 20 projects, it would make sense for each team member to merge a project at a time, resolve the conflicts then commit and push to a remote so that the other team members can get the merge work that has been completed.

Here's a scenario:

- There are 3 branches: master, A and B. A was branched off master and B was branched off A.
- Branch A is continually updated but regularly pushed into master.
- B has a lot of work done on it but hasn't had A merged into it for a long time.
- A needs to be merged into B to get B as close as it can to A to make sure everything works correctly before ultimately merging B into A (then A can go into master and B can be deleted)

The problem we've come across is that as soon as a team member pushes their A->B merge work into B, git assumes that the entire merge from A into B merge has been resolved.

e.g. Say the first team member wants to merge Branch A's *Project1* into Branch B's *Project1*. They makes a branch off B (call it *B-submerge*) and then merge A into *B-submerge*, fix the conflicts in *Project1* then stage, commit and push the *Project1* files into B.

This then makes git believe there is no further merge work required when merging from A->B. That means that when another team member attempts to make their own *B-sumbmerge2* and merge A into into it in order to resolve the conflicts in *Project2*, git thinks there's no work to be done.

Is there a strategy that can be used to handle this situation?

Comment: Have you considered using submodules instead of one giant git repository?

Comment: The current repository doesn't use modules but it could be something to look at in the future.

Comment: When team 1 resolves the project1 conflicts, I assume they also sort of batch "resolves" the conflicts for the other projects. I assume that is why Git assumes all is resolved.  What happens if you don't do the push (I hope you mean merge back) to B from B-submerge, but instead make one submerge branch for each project.  Then create an integration branch off B, where you merge the different subs together.  Somehow this way it should possible to find a way.  When I find myself in this sort of situation, I always draw up a pointer diagram of the git branches to sort out the way I have to merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### History

So, you have the following branches, right?

```
 --o--o--------------o-----o--------o--------o   master 
       \            /     /        /        /          
        \          /     /        /        /           
         o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o   A
                \                                      
                 \                                     
                  o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o   B
```

I interpret the description up till (not including) "push the Project1 files into B" as approximately the following git commands:

```
cd /the/source/project1
get checkout -b project1.B_submerge B
git merge A
# Fix the conflicts
git add $the_modified_files_in_project1
git commit -m "Merge of branch A into project1"
```

### Problem

At this point you want to merge the branch `project1.B_submerge` to `B` without carrying on the "something is merged from A" property that the merge from `A` caused (e.g. create the `X` version below).

```
---------o--------o   master
    /        /
   /        /
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o   A
                     \
                      \
--o--o--o--o--o-----------------X   B
               \        \      *
                \        \    *
                 o--------o--o   project1.B_submerge
```

### Solution

This can be done by using the `git apply` command.

```
cd /the/source/project1
git checkout B
git diff B project1.B_submerge | git apply
git add .
git commit -m "Merge of project1.B_submerge using git apply"
```

The `git apply` command takes a patch and applies to the the current branch, and by feeding it the diff from the current branch and anything else, it will effectively make the current branch 100% identical with the content of that anything else.

So this will make the content of the `B` branch identical to the content of the `project1.B_submerge` branch but without any merge references. Notice this will be a single "squashed" commit though.

---

NB This will completely discard any commits made on `B` after the `get checkout -b project1.B_submerge B` command. If this is a possibility create a target branch with

```
git checkout -b target_B $(git merge-base B project1.B_submerge B)
```

and use that instead of `B` in the git apply command section above, followed by a merge or rebase to the tip of `B`.

Comment: For those wondering, the ascii drawings were made with [aewan](http://aewan.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This strategy seems a good one. Just to sum up, I've created an 'integration' branch off 'B' and for each resolved project done in sub branches off 'B' (that have had 'A' merged into it first), I've created a patch and then applied it to the 'integration' branch. All future branches off 'B' should then then merge 'A' into it first, then checkout specific project folders from 'integration' e.g. `git checkout origin/integration -- project_dir` that have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

@hlovdal 's answer is a good one but I'll elaborate on it.

The trick is to create an 'integration' branch off 'B' that never has 'A' merged into it. This prevents any confusion in git in regards to merge history.

For each sub branch off 'B'

- Merge in 'A'
- Unstage all the changes that automatically show up on account of the merge.
- Resolve *project1* merge conflicts.
- Stage and Commit all added, removed and modified files for *project1*
- Create a diff/patch between the point before and after *project1* was committed e.g. `git diff e5ffdee a3ae287 > merge_project1.diff`

Now, in the *integration* branch, apply the patch with `git apply <path to patch file>/merge_project1.diff`

From there, another person working on merging *project2* can now get the *project1* fixes. Assuming they've already merged A into their branch off B, they:

- can now checkout the changes made to *project1* (now that they exist in *integration*) using `git checkout origin/integration -- project1_dir`
- commit the the *project1* changes (to their local branch)
- resolve the *project2* changes
- submit and commit the *project2* changes
- Create a patch based on the diff from before and after than the *project2* commit.
- Apply the patch to *integration*

When everything is complete, *integration* can be merged into *A*.